# Failed with exit Code 245 xCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, build

ERROR:

> clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal 11 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang
>   failed with exit code 245

I researched, but I can't find how can I fix that?

Comment: http://forgecode.net/2010/11/the-modern-runtime-and-clang-1-6s-shadowed-variables-bug/

Comment: Also http://groups.google.com/group/asihttprequest/browse_thread/thread/c66b58910f92b638?pli=1

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is far too unspecific for anyone to be of real help here. This is akin to saying "My car doesn't start, how can I fix it?". If you need/want help, provide more information about the problem, such as commands invoked, what you looked at to figure out what the error meant, any pertinent code, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your project there is same name interface or file may be exist so this give an error